# Tomcat 8.0.32 - updated shared library not used by web apps

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, shared-libraries

I have a tomcat 8.0.32 running on windows.

In the folder tomcat\lib I have a shared.jar file.
shared.jar is a global shared library used by all web applications.
This file contains a java class containing a constant:

```
public final int CONSTANTVALUE = 1000;
```

I have 2 web applications which are using this CONSTANTVALUE. 
I delete shared.jar and copy a new shared.jar into the tomcat\lib which has a new constant value:

```
public final int CONSTANTVALUE = 2000;
```

I restart windows (and tomcat) but the applications are still seeing value "1000" from old version of shared.jar.

I have confirmed that this class only exists under the tomcat\lib folder and nowhere else. The applications WEB-INF\lib do NOT have this jar.

If I delete shared.jar then the web applications fail to run due to ClassNotFoundException (confirmation that shared.jar is being used).

If I redeploy the web applications they pick up the new constant value "2000"

Why/How does tomcat remember the old version of shared.jar ?

Why do I have to redeploy the web applications for them to pick up that shared.jar has been replaced with new code ? (defeats the purpose of shared libraries)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a java issue not Tomcat. Java compilation uses Constant folding (inlines constant values) thereby removing dependency to shared libraries.

Using techniques to avoid constant folding I managed to enforce the dependency to the shared library.